# How can I get the alternating rows in different columns web scraping with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
records=[]
for artist_name in artist_name_list_items:
    names = artist_name.contents
    print(names)
    records.append((names))
```

This is the output of the written code but the year I want in a diff column as I add this in a data frame it appear in a single column.

```
['Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens']
['2015']
['Avengers: Endgame']
['2019']
['Avatar']
['2009']
['Black Panther']
['2018']
['Avengers: Infinity War']
['2018']
['Titanic']
['1997']
['Jurassic World']
['2015']
['The Avengers']
['2012']
['Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi']
['2017']
['Incredibles 2']
['2018']
```

Please help me sort this up. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome. I see you tagged this with `web-scraping`, but the question doesn't appear to be referring to any web scraping technologies. Is that still relevant? If not, I'd remove that tag.

Comment: Also, are you sure that's the right query for this output? The query seems to be working exclusively with `artist_name`, but your data is outputting title and year. On quick glance, your query doesn't appear to map to your output.

Comment: Fixing the formatting of question and some grammars.

Comment: You might wanna double check your scraping. There should be some difference in the selectors for each of this data in a page. Separate it out at the source.